# Tried to get the bounds of a focus node that didn't have its context set yet

Tags: flutter

The following error occurred when the user switched to another app returned to my application and filled in data in the text field.
The app screen is OTP filled with Custom Keyboard (KeyboardActionsItem).
I user focus note and next focus when the text length == 1
IF it is returned from another app and filled number, a focus note  occurs  following error

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Tried to get the bounds of a focus node that didn't have its context set yet.
The context needs to be set before trying to evaluate traversal policies. Setting the context is typically done with the attach method.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart':
Failed assertion: line 822 pos 7: 'context != null'

Please Show me how should i handle this error if you have ideas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.